# Converting longitude and latitude coordinates to Indian Grid system?

Tags: coordinate-system, georeferencing, latitude-longitude, india

How to convert lat/long coordinates to Indian Grid system?

I've googled for a couple of days but didnt find the exact algorithm for this.

and i got a link [Indian Grid System](https://deeppradhan.heliohost.org/gis/indian-grid/).

but i didnt get a picture how the zones(there are 9 zones) are divided among india and how to convert the coordinates?

Comment: Your link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform that transformation using [cs2cs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/cs2cs.1.html), a tool that is part of the [Proj4](http://proj.osgeo.org/) package. In case of need, you can find the proj strings for the Indian system(s) at [SpatialReference.org](http://spatialreference.org/ref/?search=Kalianpur%20India&srtext=Search).

Comment: You might also check http://www.epsg-registry.org. Disclosure: I'm on the subcommittee that maintains it.

Comment: @luis mkennedy when i convert using cs2cs from epsg:4326 to epsg:24379(india zone IIa) what i get is x, y right? and what is GR then? are they both different? i am new to these topics. and one thing i found is [convertor](http://kanchu_deep.tripod.com/igconv.htm) so i am in confusion now what is eastings,northings,x,y

Comment: I don't know what GR is in this context, could you detail? If you don't know what easting and northing are then you perhaps should read [something on Cartography](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=introduction+to+cartography&t=canonical) before going further.

Comment: @Luís de Sousa here this eastings and northings called as GR (as i understood). see this [grid system](http://kanchu_deep.tripod.com/igintro.htm). now, Is x,y and eastings,northings are different? because the values are different when i use "cs2cs" and [convertor](http://kanchu_deep.tripod.com/igconv.htm)

Comment: @mkennedy from this [indian grid](http://kanchu_deep.tripod.com/igintro.htm) it was saying there are nine zones and in [epsg-registry.org](http://www.epsg-registry.org/) i cannot find all 9 zones. so which one i should follow

Comment: @LuísdeSousa, GR = grid reference. Sandy, sometimes a GR = xy/easting,northing, but sometimes the values are concatenated as the intro to IGS website says or are combined with letters or other information (like MGRS / USNG). If EPSG doesn't have a zone, it's because they haven't had anyone tell them it's in use. If you don't have the zone parameter values, you're not going to be able to use them either!

Comment: @Sandy, IIIb and IVb would cover middle and southern Myanmar. They're likely not in current use. Ah, Cliff Mugnier reports that IIIb is still used in Myanmar: http://www.asprs.org/a/resources/grids/10-2013-Burma.pdf

Comment: listings are also available at http://epsg.io/?q=Kalianpur

Answer (score -2):

GR refers to the Grid Reference, it's like a lat long intersection. Eastings are grid lines that akin to longitude(lines that increase towards the East) and Northings are like latitude (lines that increase towards the North). The intersection of the two is known as the GR or grid reference.

Comment: This does not really answer the question, which I think is more about the maths of the conversion.